# Is it possible to set the compression level for a jpeg image in WebImage class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-uploading

Is it possible to set the compression level for a jpeg image in `WebImage` class? Or would i have to use the `Image` class for this?

Comment: doesn't look like it

Comment: Seems you must use `Image`

Comment: you could open a pull request to implement it if you cared enough about it!

Comment: Nah.. It's not that important. I just asked because the amount/size of code for re-naming, re-sizing and converting an uploaded image to jpeg with the `WebImage` class is much shorter then with the `Image` class. The only downside is that i can't find a way to set the compression level of the image. I guess that i will have to go with the `Image` class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Image to compact it first. After compacted, you could use this on WebImage.

Here is a sample where I convert a base64 to image, but try to understand the compress logic (the 80L is the level of compression):

```
public MemoryStream Base64ToJpeg(string imgFoto)
{
    Image imagemASerAjustada = null;
    Bitmap bmpTemporario = null;
    MemoryStream imagemCompactadaStream = new MemoryStream();
    EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    try
    {
        // removemos o cabeçalho a respeito do tipo da imagem
        string base64 = imgFoto.Substring(imgFoto.IndexOf(',') + 1);
        base64 = base64.Trim('\0');
        // convertemos em um array de bytes
        byte[] img = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

        // transformamos a base64 em imagem
        imagemASerAjustada = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(img));
        // convertemos a imagem em Bitmap
        bmpTemporario = new Bitmap(imagemASerAjustada, new Size(140, 140));
        ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        // Create an EncoderParameters object.
        // An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter
        // objects. In this case, there is only one
        // EncoderParameter object in the array.
        Encoder myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
        using (EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 80L))
        { 
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
            bmpTemporario.Save(imagemCompactadaStream, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        }
        return imagemCompactadaStream;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (imagemCompactadaStream.Length > 0)
        { 
            imagemASerAjustada.Dispose();
            bmpTemporario.Dispose();
            myEncoderParameters.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

```
    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
    {
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
        {
            return codec;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can save the Stream in the WebImage(Stream)

Comment: But if i do it this way i would end up with using twice as much memory as i would have the stream in memory twice. Or am i wrong? If i understood you correctly, then i would do the compression with the `Image` class and the rest with `WebImage`?

Comment: In the example, the MemoryStream are used as a tool to manage the stream of the image. If you try to manage the stream with the same MemoryStream, probably you'll get an error. You can use Image or WebImage, however, you'll need to use a "middleware" to do the compression.